# Solving second order differential equation - why can't I do it this way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a second order differential equation $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\omega^2x$, the textbook approach is to substitute $x(t)=e^{rt}$. From this, we get $x(t)=e^{\pm i\omega t}$.

I tried to solve it in a different way that apparently does not work, and I just wanted to understand why - and exactly which step is wrong.

[My approach that didn't work](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/a5d17390-dc82-45f7-a378-723c8c047477/Doodles.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20221221%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221221T000440Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=a3dbac4f7a7058ea814164b880b88b77445306ad97d57d43833edfd28c6a507c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22Doodles.pdf%22&x-id=GetObject)

Comment: For one thing, when you divide by $x$ in step (2), that $1/x$  should be outside on the left hand side, I mean, not as part of the function you take $d/dt$ of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to try exponentials in principle.

You can solve this equation using separation twice. For that, you should express the left hand side as $vdv/dx$, where $v=dx/dt$. You find $v(x)$ first and then you integrate the resulting first order equation by separation again.

In other words, you first get energy conservation (a finite relation between $v$ and $x$) and integrate again to get $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The step
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\dfrac{dx}{dt} \frac{1}{x} = -\omega^2
$$
going to
$$
\frac{d}{dt}dx \frac{1}{x} = -\omega^2{dt}
$$
is not true. The $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is still within the operator $\frac{d}{dt}$. So you can not separate out and integrate like you would do in some other separable odes (though whilst it looks like multiplying deltas around and integrating, this is learnt jump)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity:
\begin{align*}
x'' = -\omega^{2}x & \Longleftrightarrow 2x''x' = -2\omega^{2}x'x\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x')^{2} = -\omega^{2}x^{2} + k \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x' = \pm\sqrt{k - \omega^{2}x^{2}}
\end{align*}
where the last ODE is separable.